# Как записать значение из input в переменную PHP?

Tags: php, переменные

Есть два input: `first_name` и `last_name` в файле *index.php*, также есть `$first_name` и `$last_name` в *config.php*. Как записать значения из input'ов в переменные? Не присвоить, а именно записать эти значения. Чтобы после выполнения скрипта я мог открыть config.php и увидеть там эти значения.

Вопрос, скорее всего, тупой, понимаю. Только второй день в PHP. Наверное, я неправильно гуглю, уже полтора часа на это потратил.

Comment: `file_get_contents(...)`, `preg_replace(...)` и `file_put_contents(...)`, но вопрос реально тупой. Ибо с таким подходом далеко не уехать

Comment: Насчет оценки вопроса соглашусь. В принципе, запись конфига в файл - стандартная операция, и для этого есть даже стандартная функция. Но переменные с именами  first_name и last_name **никогда** на пишут в конфиг. То есть ты что-то делаешь неправильно

Comment: Спасибо. Решил записать в базу данных просто. Думаю, так будет правильнее.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Насколько я понял, вы хотите хранить данные о пользователе. В таком случае, лучше использовать базу данных, самый простой вариант это `mysql`. Подход который вы описываете не очень удачен, так как файлы с расширением `.php` это исполняемые файлы и они не годятся для хранения данных. Если вы хотите хранить конфигурацию приложения, то лучше использовать `.env` файл или `yaml`. Если же тема базы данных для вас пока-что слишком сложна, то на этапе обучения можно хранить данные в обычном текстовом файле, записать данный в файл можно с помощью функции `file_put_contents(...)` . Так же, в вашем случае, более предпочтительнее хранить данные в `json` формате. json очень простой и распространенный формат, думаю, не будет труда в нем разобраться и в будущем эти знания очень пригодятся. Удачи в изучении)

Comment: Спасибо. Да, сделал это на mysql.